# How to add a transparent border to a table cell in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242227/is-it-a-bug-in-chrome-to-display-a-border-on-a-cell-where-none-is-defined) was closed before I could get a full answer, so I'll phase this one a bit differently.

In Chrome, it appears that if you set a border-bottom on one table cell you have to set a border-bottom on all the cells in the same row, otherwise Chrome doesn't know what to do with the unaccounted space.

[It was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242619/65387) that I simply use a white border to make it appear as though the other cells do not have a border. But what if I have a gradient background, and don't want a white line to appear?

It appears that [`1px solid transparent`](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/YZBXn/4/) does not have any affect. [`rgba`](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/YZBXn/5/) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse) it all boils down to the `border-collapse` property:

> The separated model is the traditional HTML table border model.
>   Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance
>   between them given by the border-spacing property.
>
> In the collapsed border model, adjacent table cells share borders. In
>   that model, the border-style value of inset behaves like groove, and
>   outset behaves like ridge.

Change `border-collapse` to separate and it works fine: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YZBXn/8/)**

Comment: Ah! That's what CBroe was talking about. I'm still not 100% sure why it would behave this way though; presumably that border is shared with the cell below, which doesn't have a border defined. So...where's it coming from?

Oh.....oh nevermind. It does. Because of colspan! That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is either a bug or a different interpretation of the `border-collapse` property in Chrome.  It seems to work fine (as intended) if you remove `border-collapse: collapse` from `<table>`: http://jsfiddle.net/YZBXn/6/

An alternative would be to use another element contained in the table cell that has the border.

```
<td><div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;width:1.5in;">&nbsp;</div></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZBXn/7/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `1px solid transparent` is transparent to the 'border' underneath that is stretched from the previous sibling `<td>`. A better way would be to not use a table.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get it to align without tables. The text beneath needs to line up with the underlines.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work without resorting to transparent.

```
<table>
    <tr><td id=cell1>bleah</td><td id=cell2>bleah</td></tr>
    <tr><td id=cell3>blah</td><td id=cell4>blah</td></tr>
</table>

#cell1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#cell4 {
    border-bottom: 9px dotted red;
}
```